# Interest Rate sensitivity due to floating rate liabilites

Tags: interest-rates, floating-rate, sensitivities

I am new to finance, so please bear with me
I am supposed to find the change in 'interest expense' when the borrowing rate goes up by 50bps. The liabilities include both fixed and floating rate liabilities. I have done it as follows:
I separated the floating rate amount from the total debt amount and then calculated 50*0.01% of this amount to get the change in interest cost.
Is this the correct way to do it? I understand that I should probably calculate the duration of these liabilities, but shouldn't this way also work since these are floating rate instruments?

Comment: If you just want to calculate expense incurred (so higher interest paid) due to interest rate increase then your calculation is correct. Notice that if you multiply 0.50% by the outstanding notional, you are calculating interest incurred _per_ year. You don't need duration, you would only need it to calculate change in PV of outstanding debt.

Comment: and change in PV will only happen for fixed-rate liabilities, right?